# Android VideoView not expanding when populating inside a ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-videoview

This video view doesn't expand and put my video in the view.  If I set static height and width (e.g 640dp 400dp) the video successfully populates the view and works as expected.

This problem arose after I moved into the ScrollView setup - it used to work fine when it was in its own parent LinearLayout.

XML of VideoView:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/gray">


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/top_video"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <VideoView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:id="@+id/video_view" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <!---- many more layouts and views that all get hidden when setting above to visible -->
        <!---- many more layouts and views that all get hidden when setting above to visible -->

     </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `android:fillViewPort=true` to your scroll view and match parent height

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewPort=true
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/gray">
```